# Is there an easy way to make a view into a pressable link?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a scroll view which holds a number of smaller views. I just want to make it so that I can press on one and it will flip to safari and go to a specified link address. Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add transparent button of the size of the view to each view and add IBActions to them

```
-(IBAction)buttonOnViewOneTapped:(id)sender {
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://yourURLhere.com"]];
}
```

just a simple example.

Hope it helps

Comment: You can even make the smaller views UIButtons themselves

Comment: @Jodocus how would I do that?

Comment: and what do you mean when you say add IBActions to them?

Comment: @SirYakalot if you are working with .xib then you need to connect an IBAction method to an action of an UIButton. If you are building everything in the code use something like that `[viewOneButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonOnViewOneTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];`. And then the return type of that method can be `void`

Comment: I guess you create the smaller views by calling something like `[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:...` Just alloc an UIButton instead of a UIView, since UIButton is a subclass of UIView. UIButton uses another designated initializer so do something like this: `[UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom]`
But since UIButton wants to show an UIImage, things might get more complex than Novarg's solution